# docker-compose returning ERROR: build path either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL. after update

Tags: docker, container, docker-compose

around last week I updated my system (Arch Arm on raspberry pi using `pacman -Syu`) and after that update every time I try to run `docker-compose up -d` I get :

`ERROR: build path /srv/http/revProxy either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL.`
Although I have built the relevant image along with all the others specified in this docker-compose.yml file multiple times over the last year without issue.
I can assure you the directory exists and contains a Dockerfile so I'm unsure as to what is going on.

The portion that I assume is generating this issue is :

```
version: "3.8"

services:

  reverse-proxy:
    container_name: reverseProxy
    build:
      context: ../http/revProxy/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports: 
      - "192.168.1.254:80:80"
      - "192.168.1.254:443:443"
    volumes:
      - "../http/revProxy/httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf" 
      - "../http/revProxy/httpd-vhosts.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:ro"
      - "../http/revProxy/SSLCerts/fullchain.pem:/usr/local/apache2/conf/server.crt:ro"
      - "../http/revProxy/SSLCerts/privkey.pem:/usr/local/apache2/conf/server.key:ro"
    restart: always
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.0.8
      myothernetwork_default:
        ipv4_address: 182.16.0.5
```

Any ideas on why this may be?  I am desperate at this point.

Comment: Some information about the location in the error may be of some use to help troubleshoot your issue: `ls -la /srv/http/revProxy`.